# Running sklearn trained classifier in a windows machine without Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a classifier (and vectorizer) that I can export as a pickled model. I am using Python.

This is on my local machine. Now, in order to perform the classifications in "production" I need to be able to run this in another machine that does not have Python installed. Any idea how to do this? Is it possible to create a Python executable with the pickled model in it?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do is to get Python installed properly on your production system. If you aren't able to do this for whatever reason, you can still run Python without installing it, but it's a bit more work to get everything to work properly, particularly if you don't have Administrator privileges.

If you truly can't install Python, your best bet would probably be to use something like [py2exe](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) to build a self-contained version of your application that includes a Python interpreter and required libraries.

Comment: This is about as good as it is going to get. The premise of the question is kind of funny, considering the pickled model is a Python object. "I want to do something with a Python object but uh, can't have Python."